# How to set a remote environment variable with Expect?

Tags: perl, expect

I'm doing this within Perl, using the Expect Perl module. Anyway, after logging in and getting prompt, I am trying to verify that I was actually able to get a prompt, and I am trying to set PS1. I am setting the remote prompt to 'Expect #', but the output from setting exp_internal to 1 is not what I am expecting.

I am setting it as follows:

```
$exp->send("export PS1='Expect # '\r");
```

And then matching as follows

```
qr/(?<!export PS1=.)Expect #\s?(?!export)/
```

And here's output that I see when setting exp_internal to 1:

```
\033]0;root@localhost:~\007Expect # '
```

I don't understand why after setting my PS1 to 'Expect # ' that it is still showing the original prompt (i.e., [root@localhost:~ ]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Expect qw( );

my $exp = Expect->new();
#$exp->exp_internal(1);
$exp->spawn('bash') or die;

$exp->send("export PS1='Expect ''# '\r");

say "\n\nMatched rule ", $exp->expect(1, "Expect #") // 'TIMEOUT';
```

(Note that I changed the `send` a little to use a literal string for the prompt since I couldn't figure out how to specify a regex for the prompt. You've wasted a lot of our time by not demonstrating your problem.)

Output:

```
export PS1='Expect ''# '

{1} ikegami@host [~]$ export PS1='Expect ''# '
Expect #

Matched rule 1
```

Since I didn't wait for the original prompt before calling `send`, I still see the original prompt, but that's no biggie since I'm not listening for that prompt.